# Does WSO2 Identity server provide JWKS

Tags: wso2, openid

wir are trying to authenticate against WSO2 Identity server with the mitreid-connect client (https://github.com/mitreid-connect). We are running into problems when the client tries to validate the idToken that WSO2 returns. For successfully validating it, the public key is needed. Usually this is provided in the JWK (Json web key standard), and is available on the identity-provider-server.

Does WSO2 have such a JWK Endpoint ? Or is it in a file somewhere in the installation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe that WSO2 only supports the Basic Client Profile of OpenID Connect in which case you don't need to validate (well at least cryptograpically verify the issuer of) the ID token yourself since it is returned from a TLS protected endpoint at the Provider. That may be why there's no JWKs URL.